# Specifying specific wildcard conditions in regex

Tags: c#, regex, wildcard

I want to be able to do a string search for the following:

```
[DOUBLE_QUOTE] [ANY_COMBINATION_OF_SPACES_AND_TABS] [COMMA] [ANY_COMBINATION_OF_SPACES_AND_TABS] [DOUBLE_QUOTE]
```

The tricky part for me is identifying the [ANY_COMBINATION_OF_SPACES_AND_TABS].  How can I accomplish this using a regex in C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
[ \t]
```

Would match a space or a tab. To match any number of these (including 0) you could use the `*` quantifier:

```
[ \t]*
```

Use the `+` quantifier if you mean 1 or more, eg: `[ \t]+`

If you mean any whitespace you could use `\s` instead of `[ \t]`.

Answer (score 0):

In regex `\s` covers any kind of white spaces including tabs(`\t`). So you can easily use `\s` for this.

But if you want to ignore the others and only strict to space and tab, then you can use this one as well.

```
[ \t]+
```

Answer (score 0):

On the whole, it could probably be one of these

`"[ \t]*,[ \t]*"`
or
`"\h*,\h*"`